# Return array one dimension from array_map

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a lot of record (element) in an array like this, basically from query with union all 'keyword' :

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 16
        [no_surat] => E1679
        [level] => B
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 16
        [no_surat] => E1679
        [level] => C
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 169
        [no_surat] => E1736
        [level] => B
    )
)
```

I need to get those element into format like this :

```
Array
(
[16] => E1679 - B
[16] => E1679 - C
[169] => E1736 - B
)
```

So, I try to use array_map function like this :

```
$listNoEstimate = array_map(function ($insert) {
    return array(
        $insert['id'] => $insert['no_surat'] . ' - ' . $insert ['level']
    );
}, $listNoEstimate);
```

The result is like this :

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [16] => E1679 - B
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [16] => E1679 - C
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [169] => E1736 - B
    )
)
```

Please advise

Comment: FYI: you can't have duplicate keys in your array, your desired results can't be achieved

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible anyway,

Instead you can do something like this,

```
$result = [];
foreach($listNoEstimate as $k => $v){
     $result[$v['id']][] = $v['no_surat'].' - '.$v['level'];    
}
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: Okey, Seems I can use it to create optgroup

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to do this thing directly, although you can do it like this

```
for($i=0;$i<count($listNoEstimate);$i++){
    $j=0;
    foreach($listNoEstimate[$i] as $key => $value){
        $temp[$j]=$value;
        $j++;
    }
    $listNoEstimate[$temp[0]]=$temp[1]-$temp[2];
}
```

**Note:** This method work properly, if your `[id] => 16` is unique. Otherwise it will replace previous data.